# ajax submitting forms using FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, multipartform-data

I was trying to submit only specific inputs of a very large form and I wanted to do this using ajax. I had this and it was working fine. This will submit all inputs within #someDiv.

```
$(".save").click(function () {

    dat = $.param($('#someDiv').find('input'));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "...",
        data: dat,
        success: function(data) {
            //success
        }
    });
});
```

I then remembered that some of these inputs are file inputs so this will not work. I did some research and found that using FormData was the way to go:

```
$(".save").click(function () {

    dat = new FormData($('#someDiv').find('input'));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "...",
        data: dat,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //success
        }
    });
});
```

But this function is not working, the success function  is firing but nothing is saving so I assume the FormData is not being created properly. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try serialize()?

Comment: I think you are mistake about what find returns.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: i use `FormData` only when I include data like pictures, files, ... and if you want to create a new FormData it should be a Form and not regular data, use `new FormData($('form')[0])` instead. If you want to send strings use `$('form').serialize()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create a formData as below

`dat = new FormData($('#someDiv').find('input'));`

you need to pass the Javascript form reference to the form , for example if the id of the form is , singupForm then do it like below

`dat = new FormData($('#singupForm')[0]);`

**Edit**

In case you want to add only selected field you can do it as below

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("variable", "First Value");
    formData.append("integerVariable", 987654321); 

    // For file, remember to pass the JavaScript reference
    formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);
```

Comment: So I can't pass only certain inputs of #signupForm to create formdata?